# How to declare an XML namespace prefix with DOM/PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to produce the following XML by means of DOM/PHP5:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:p="myNS">
  <p:x>test</p:x>
</root>
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$root = $xml->createElementNS('myNS', 'root');
$xml->appendChild($root);
$x = $xml->createElementNS('myNS', 'x', 'test');
$root->appendChild($x);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="myNS">
  <x>test</x>
</root>
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make this prefix working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$root = $xml->createElementNS('myNS', 'root');
```

`root` shouldn't be in namespace `myNS`. In the original example, it is in no namespace.

```
$x = $xml->createElementNS('myNS', 'x', 'test');
```

Set a qualifiedName of `p:x` instead of just `x` to suggest to the serialisation algorithm that you want to use `p` as the prefix for this namespace. However note that to an XML-with-Namespaces-aware reader there is no semantic difference whether `p:` is used or not.

This will cause the `xmlns:p` declaration to be output on the `<p:x>` element (the first one that needs it). If you want the declaration to be on the root element instead (again, there is no difference to an XML-with-Namespaces reader), you will have to `setAttributeNS` it explicitly. eg.:

```
$root = $xml->createElementNS(null, 'root');
$xml->appendChild($root);
$x = $xml->createElementNS('myNS', 'p:x', 'test');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:p', 'myNS');
$root->appendChild($x);
```

Comment: Wow you explained this really well and this one answer has really helped me to understand how namespaces really work in PHP DOM!

Comment: @bobince Is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530580/domdocumentload-namespace-default-prefix-was-not-found-in-entity related to this issue?