# DOMDocument::load(): Namespace default prefix was not found in Entity

Tags: php, xml, xml-entities

I am parsing some XML with PHP DOMDocument. This is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->resolveExternals = true;
$doc->substituteEntities = true;
$doc->load('../poems_xml/'.$pid.'.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('../xslt/title.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$ptitle = $proc->transformToXML($doc);
```

I have an entity file declared at the beginning of my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?oxygen RNGSchema="../dtd/dps.rng" type="xml"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../dtd/dps.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "../dtd/entities.ent">
[...]
```

And the entities file looks like this:

```
[...]
<!ENTITY d1_AytR_002 "<rs key='d1_AytR_002'>d1_AytR_002</rs>">
[...]
```

In my .xml I use these entities like so:

```
...&d1_AytR_002;...
```

Now, it all goes well in terms of parsing the file and transform it via the xslt and css files, except for the entities. They just get ignored. Turning on the php_error_log flag, I get this:

```
Notice: DOMDocument::load(): Namespace default prefix was not found in Entity, line: 1 in index.php on line 28
```

(line 28 of `index.php` is where the `load('../poems_xml/'.$pid.'.xml')` instruction is). Can someone shed some light on what I should check/add regarding my entities?

I'm using PHP 5.6.40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround (and possible permanent solution) is that of adding the namespace to each of the `<!ENTITY>`s, like so:

```
<!ENTITY d1_AytR_002 "<rs xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" key='d1_AytR_002'>d1_AytR_002</rs>">
```