# PHP simpleXml issue with several attributes

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I have a xml node to create like this :

```
 <Document xmlns="blabla" xmlns:xsi="blablablabla" xsi:schemaLocation="blablablablablabla">
```

I did in my code several tests:

CASE 1

```
    $document = $this->_xml;
    $document->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns', self::XMLNS);
    $document->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi", self::XMLNS_XSI);
    $document->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation", self::XSI_SCHEMALOCATION);
```

which gives me :

```
<Document xmlns="blabla" xsi="blablablabla" xsi:schemaLocation="blablablablablabla">
```

So here all the xmln attributes are overriden by the xsi attribute.

CASE 2
When I add the prefix xmlns for last node :

```
    $document = $this->_xml;
    $document->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi", self::XMLNS_XSI, self::XMLNS);
    $document->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation", self::XSI_SCHEMALOCATION);
```

which gives me :

```
<Document xmlns:xmlns="blabla" xmlns:xsi="blablablabla" xsi:schemaLocation="blablablabla">
```

CASE 3
and when I try the easiest version it totally fails :

```
    $document = $this->_xml;
    $document->addAttribute('xmlns', self::XMLNS);
    $document->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi", self::XMLNS_XSI);
    $document->addAttribute("xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation", self::XSI_SCHEMALOCATION);
```

which gives me :

```
<Document xmlns:xmlns="blabla" xmlns="blabla" xmlns:xsi="blablablabla" xsi:schemaLocation="blablablablablabla">
```

How can I have all my 3 attributes xmlns, xmlns:xsi and xsi:schemaLocation correctly in my node?

Please note that I solved a first issue thanks to this post : 
[Unable add namespace with PHPs SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592665/unable-add-namespace-with-phps-simplexml)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it was well formatted with case 1, but firefox was badly interpreting the node.